# I deleted swap partition, what more I should do?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, swap

Well I deleted my swap partition using gparted just because I needed one more primary partition and the swap was the 4th, that is the maximum number of primary partitions. I think I don't need it anyway.

The question is: Is anything more that I should do to disable swap from the system ? I'm afraid that the system can anytime try to write anything on the swap partition that doesn't exist anymore and maybe crash... I don't know. Well I don't know even if the system will restart normally the next time.

Oh one more thing... Can I create a swap page file or something inside of os partition just to hibernate ? Does it make sense ?

Forgive me if I said anything stupid. I'm new to linux. I'm using ubuntu 12.10 btw. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system will recognize the partition, and will not try to use it as a swap partition.

Use can create a swap file in a partition. There's a good guide here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

(I'm wondering btw - why do you need an extra primary partition? Why can't you use an extended partition?)

If you need more than 4 partitions, the best method is to make your 4th partition **Extended Partition** (as large as you may need) and then create many more **Logical Partitions** under it.

Comment: Thanx for the reply Sadi. The first partition is the windows boot partition (I dont know how it is called), the second is the windows itself, the third is the linux ext4 partition, and the 4th partition is the partition that I needed to create to put my files to be usable on both windows and linux so I formated it as ntfs.

Comment: @dunego it was actually **Trond** who answered, I only added the last paragraph. As I said, you can create an **Extended** Partition at the 4th position, and then create, say, 2 **Logical** Partitions: one large **NTFS** partition and one, say, 4GB **swap** partition so that Ubuntu will be happier ;-)